# Make python code continue after exception

Tags: python

I'm trying to read all files from a folder that matches a certain criteria. My program crashes once I have  an exception raised. I am trying to continue even if there's an exception but it still stops executing.

This is what I  get after a couple of seconds.

```
error <type 'exceptions.IOError'>
```

Here's my code

```
import os 
path = 'Y:\\Files\\'
listing = os.listdir(path)
try:
    for infile in listing:
        if infile.startswith("ABC"):
            fo = open(infile,"r")
            for line in fo:
                if line.startswith("REVIEW"):
                    print infile
            fo.close()
except:
    print "error "+str(IOError)
    pass
```

Comment: "I am trying to continue even if there's an exception"- never do this unless you have a clear plan for how your program should continue. Assuming that your code after the except: block relies on the file contents, continuing on after an IO error is a bad idea. Let the exception crash the program instead, so that you can actually notice and fix the underlying problem.

Comment: Beside the point, but [a bare `except` is bad practice](/q/54948548/4518341). Instead, use the specific exception you're expecting like `except IOError`, or at least `except Exception`.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Put your `try/except` structure more in-wards. Otherwise when you get an error, it will break all the loops.

Perhaps after the first for-loop, add the `try/except`. Then if an error is raised, it will continue with the next file.

```
for infile in listing:
    try:
        if infile.startswith("ABC"):
            fo = open(infile,"r")
            for line in fo:
                if line.startswith("REVIEW"):
                    print infile
            fo.close()
    except:
        pass
```

This is a perfect example of why you should use a `with` statement here to open files. When you open the file using `open()`, but an error is catched, the file will remain open forever. *Now is better than never*.

```
for infile in listing:
    try:
        if infile.startswith("ABC"):
            with open(infile,"r") as fo
                for line in fo:
                    if line.startswith("REVIEW"):
                        print infile
    except:
        pass
```

Now if an error is caught, the file will be closed, as that is what the `with` statement does.

Answer (score 11):

You're code is doing exactly what you're telling it to do. When you get an exception, it jumps down to this section:

```
except:
    print "error "+str(IOError)
    pass
```

Since there's nothing after that, the program ends.

Also, that `pass` is superfluous.

Comment: @Ankur `pass` means "do nothing". Your code will continue without it. The problem is that there's nothing for it to do after your `except` block.

Answer (score 11):

Move the try/except inside the for loop.
Like in:

```
  import os 
    path = 'C:\\'
    listing = os.listdir(path)
    for infile in listing:
        try:    
            if infile.startswith("ABC"):
                fo = open(infile,"r")
                for line in fo:
                    if line.startswith("REVIEW"):
                        print infile
                fo.close()
        except:
              print "error "+str(IOError)
```

Answer (score 2):

As per strictest interpretation of the question "continue even if there's an exception". Python gives us a keyword "finally" which executes a block of code no matter what precedes it. The only issue with this method will run a block of code regardless of the type of error, which might not be desirable for all cases.

```
try:
  unreal = 3/0 # raises divide by zero exception
  print(unreal)

# handles zerodivision exception
except :
  print("Can't divide by zero, 0 has no multiplicative inverse")

finally:
# this block is always executed
  print("Brahmagupta claimed that “zero divided by a zero is zero.”)
```