# Continue After Exception - Python

Tags: python-3.x, exception, try-catch

I am trying to have `try` and `except` block in my code to catch an error, then put it to sleep for 5 seconds and then I want to continue where it left off. Following is my code and currently as soon as it catches exception, it does not continue and stops after exception.

```
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

tries = 0

try:
    for pag_num, page in enumerate(one_submitted_jobs):
        if 'NextToken' in page:
            print("Token:",pag_num)
        else:
            print("No Token in page:", pag_num)

except ClientError as exception_obj:
    if exception_obj.response['Error']['Code'] == 'ThrottlingException':
        print("Throttling Exception Occured.")
        print("Retrying.....")
        print("Attempt No.: " + str(tries))
        time.sleep(5)
        tries +=1
    else:
        raise
```

How can I make it to continue after exception? Any help would be great.

Note - I am trying to catch AWS's `ThrottlingException` error in my code.

Following code is for demonstration to @Selcuk to show what I have currently from his answer. Following will be deleted as soon as we agree if I am doing it correct or not.

```
tries = 1
pag_num = 0

# Only needed if one_submitted_jobs is not an iterator:
one_submitted_jobs = iter(one_submitted_jobs)

while True:
    try:
        page = next(one_submitted_jobs)
        # do things
        if 'NextToken' in page:
            print("Token: ", pag_num)
        else:
            print("No Token in page:", pag_num)
        pag_num += 1
    
    except StopIteration:
        break
    
    except ClientError as exception_obj:
        # Sleep if we are being throttled
        if exception_obj.response['Error']['Code'] == 'ThrottlingException':
            print("Throttling Exception Occured.")
            print("Retrying.....")
            print("Attempt No.: " + str(tries))
            time.sleep(3)
            tries +=1
```

Comment: Continue doing _what_? Executing the `for` loop? In that case you should have the `try` inside `for`, not outside.

Comment: @Selcuk yeah execute for loop. I tried inside for loop like mentioned here [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18994375/6626093) , in that case, it doesn't catch the execption

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. In that case you should be getting the exception in the `for` line. What is `one_submitted_jobs`? Is it a generator?

Comment: You should use any iteration to work it cyclic but when you call the raise exception, it forces you to stop the loop.

Comment: @Selcuk yes, `one_submitted_jobs` is a generator and I am getting an error in `for` loop. Not sure how to continue

Comment: @toRex I understand your point, but as per my comment above, if I do that cyclic, it doesn't catch the exception.

Comment: @user9431057 give a try by skipping raise and alternately use any print function then follow this [iteration](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions)

Comment: @Selcuk and #toRex I tried `while True:/break` and it also stops after exception happens :( But for sure without break it continues for infinite loop..

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to keep running because the exception occurs in your `for` line. This is a bit tricky because in this case the `for` statement has no way of knowing if there are more items to process or not.

A workaround could be to use a `while` loop instead:

```
pag_num = 0
# Only needed if one_submitted_jobs is not an iterator:
one_submitted_jobs = iter(one_submitted_jobs)   
while True:
    try:
        page = next(one_submitted_jobs)
        # do things
        pag_num += 1
    except StopIteration:
        break
    except ClientError as exception_obj:
        # Sleep if we are being throttled
```

Comment: Appreciate your time, however, when I do this, it still stops after it finds first Client Error exception. I am clueless now :(

Comment: Stops and does what? Does it break out of the `while` loop?

Comment: I think with your method, we are sooo close. Only thing is as soon as `except ClientError as exception_obj` happens, we need to still continue until we have gone through all objects in generator/iterator. As of now, after the Client Exception, while loop break and does nothing just stops the execution.

Comment: There is nothing that could break the loop in the `except ClientError...` block. Are you sure you are executing the `ThrottlingException` clause and not the `else` part?

Comment: I am sure I did what you asked me to do. I posted the code I have for your reference. Please have a look when you can and give me a comment.